# Saving many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

For example, I have 3 classes, which I'm using for many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Library
{
    [Key]
    public string LibraryId { get; set; }
    public List<Library2Book> Library2Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
   [Key]
   public string BookId { get; set; }
   public List<Library2Book> Library2Books { get; set; }
}

public class Library2Book
{
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public string LibraryId { get; set; }
    public Library Library { get; set; }
}
```

They're configured in `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<CodeableConcept2Coding>().HasKey(k => new { k.LibraryId, k.BookId });
    builder.Entity<Library2Book>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Library)
        .WithMany(x => x.Library2Book)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.LibraryId);
    builder.Entity<Library2Book>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Book)
        .WithMany(x => x.Library2Book)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.BookId);
}
```

So, I want to add to database some list of `Library2Books`:

```
var library2Books = new List<Library2Books>(/*some sort of initialization*/);
```

What entity should I add first? `Books` or maybe `Library`? How can I do this saving?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is a simple and a very fundamental question to EF Core many-to-many relationship; I do not know why no one has written a complete example for n..m in EF Core.

I have modified your code (primary key as `int`), I do not like string in primary key. Just copy/paste the code and every should work fine.

> What entity should I add first? Books or maybe Library? How can I do this saving?

The order is not important the important thing here is the data linking. The data must be correctly linked, see the comments between my code lines.

Notes:

- Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported! You must have a join table.
- Many-to-many relationships consists of 2 separate one-to-many relationships. = 2x  1:N

  ```
  class Program
  {
     public class Library
     {
       [Key]
       public int LibraryId { get; set; }
       public List<Library2Book> Library2Books { get; set; } = new    List<Library2Book>();
     }

     public class Book
     {
       [Key]
       public int BookId { get; set; }
       public List<Library2Book> Library2Books { get; set; } = new List<Library2Book>();
     }

     public class Library2Book
     {
       [Key]
       public int BookId { get; set; }
       public Book Book { get; set; }

       [Key]
       public int LibraryId { get; set; }
       public Library Library { get; set; }
     }

     public class MyDbContext : DbContext
     {
       public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

       public DbSet<Library> Libraries { get; set; }

       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
       {
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\;Database=EFTutorial;integrated security=True;");
         base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
      }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Library2Book>().HasKey(k => new { k.LibraryId, k.BookId });

         modelBuilder.Entity<Library2Book>()
             .HasOne(x => x.Book)
             .WithMany(x => x.Library2Books)
             .HasForeignKey(x => x.BookId);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Library2Book>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Library)
            .WithMany(x => x.Library2Books)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.LibraryId);

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       }
     }

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       using (var myDb = new MyDbContext())
      {
        // Create Db
         myDb.Database.EnsureCreated();

         // I will add two books to one library
         var book1 = new Book();
         var book2 = new Book();

         // I create the library 
         var lib = new Library();

         // I create two Library2Book which I need them 
         // To map between the books and the library
         var b2lib1 = new Library2Book();
         var b2lib2 = new Library2Book();

         // Mapping the first book to the library.
         // Changed b2lib2.Library to b2lib1.Library
         b2lib1.Book = book1;
         b2lib1.Library = lib;

         // I map the second book to the library.
         b2lib2.Book = book2;
         b2lib2.Library = lib;

         // Linking the books (Library2Book table) to the library
         lib.Library2Books.Add(b2lib1);
         lib.Library2Books.Add(b2lib2);

         // Adding the data to the DbContext.
         myDb.Libraries.Add(lib);

         myDb.Books.Add(book1);
         myDb.Books.Add(book2);

         // Save the changes and everything should be working!
         myDb.SaveChanges();
       }
     }
  }
  ```

**Results**

```
Tables:   Books    |   Libraries      |    Library2Book  |
           1       |      1           |      1   |   1   |
           2       |      -           |      1   |   2   |
```

**Edit from author of the question**

When you're trying to insert a lot of entities (I've tried approximately 300), you'll have *the same key has been already added* error. You should split your inserting collection into small parts, e.g. 100 entities should be enough.

```
public async Task SaveEntities(IEnumerable<Library2Book> library2Books)
        {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var library2Book in library2Books)
                {
                    _dbContext.Set<Library>().Add(codConc2Coding.Library);
                    _dbContext.Set<Book>().Add(codConc2Coding.Book);
                    _dbContext.Set<Library2Book>().Add(library2Book);
                    i++;
                    if (i == 99)
                    {
                        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer! But I have question. to clarify some things. So, as you say, if order isn't important, if I have `var library2Books = new List<Library2Books>()`, I can add it to database like this: `myDb.Libraries.Add(library2Books.Select(x => x.Library))`, then `myDb.Books.Add(library2Books.Select(x => x.Book))`, finally `myDb.Library2Books.Add(library2Books)`?

Comment: @YuriyN. No this will not work you will get an converting you need for that at least AddRange and not Add

Comment: Sure, mistake, we need to use `AddRange`, but I can't understand exactly, why it doesn't work.

Comment: @YuriyN. I think the problem that the library2Books.It is not correctly linked or mapped to the related entities.That is exatcly what I'm trying to tell you with my answer. Can you please dump the object tree of your entities added/modified entities. This is a good way which allow me to see what is missing or what is exactly the problem in between your entities.

Comment: But the `library2Books` already contains all, what we need to insert in database. Anyway, I've found that the problem appears, when I was trying to  insert a lot of books and libraries, about 300, inserting falls down with an error _same key has been already added_, so the problem is in bulk insert with huge amount of entites.

Comment: @YuriyN. I have now a problem by loading them? can you load a libaray.Library2Books ? with it related books? if yes how did you that?

Comment: @YuriyN. I have accepted your changes, just update your changes and i will approve it. I had the same problem with key constraint and when i have linked the object corretly everything has been worked fine! I have open an issues for this qeustion in GitHub  because I think the loading is not working correctly this is a bug in EF Core https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6309

Comment: Ok, we will see how it would considered. Hope, they'll solve this problem!

Comment: Looks like the issue might be a problem with trying to save asynchronously, or the fact that you're using some sort of sequential key, if you use GUID you might get away with being able to save asynchronously _AND_ not get the duplicate key error

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue, and dropping my batch size down to 100 doesn't seem to resolve it. I am, however, wrapping all of my SaveChangesAsync() in a manually controlled transaction, which may be contributing. https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/issues/343

Comment: EF Core 5 has now the possibility of Many-to-Many relationship without explicitly mapping the join table.