# How to add list of ingredients in Many-To-Many model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, many-to-many

I have models for Vendor and Ingredient, they can see each other.
I have a list of ingredients and I need to add it somehow to vendor.
Can't understand how to do it.

```
    public void AddIngredientsToVendor(VendorIngredientsRegistrationModel model)
    {
        // Ingredients, that I want to add to wendor, Ids: [57, 59, 61, 62]
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = _repository.Fetch<Ingredient>(e => model.IngredientIds.Contains(e.Id),
                   e => e.Include(p => p.VendorIngredients)).ToList();

        var vendor = _repository.First<Vendor>(
            (e => e.Id == model.VendorId),
             e => e.Include(m => m.Ingredients));

        // How to add ingredients to Vendor?

        _repository.Update(vendor);
        _repository.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**VendorIngredient.cs**

```
public class VendorIngredient
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(VendorId))]
    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public long VendorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(IngredientId))]
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    public long IngredientId { get; set; }
}
```

**Vendor.cs**

```
public class Vendor : BaseNetworkLinkedEntity
{
    public Vendor()
    {
        Ingredients = new List<VendorIngredient>();
    }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string VendorCompanyName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VendorIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you add your model `Ingredient.cs` here as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since newer version of EF core stopped providing this pattern: [Saving many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893873/saving-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-core), so you have to manage the `bridge-table` by your own logic.

The best example that I can think of is here: [UserManager.AddToRolesAsync from ASP.NET Core IdentityFramework](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/6f9a19e829deafc04a17bd0b18ae08808e2710ab/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs#L946)

You can find this 2 methods from above link: `AddToRolesAsync` and `RemoveFromRolesAsync` as examples.

So in your case,

```
public void AddIngredientsToVendor(VendorIngredientsRegistrationModel model)
{
    // Ingredients, that I want to add to wendor, Ids: [57, 59, 61, 62]
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = _repository.Fetch<Ingredient>(e => model.IngredientIds.Contains(e.Id),
               e => e.Include(p => p.VendorIngredients)).ToList();

    var vendor = _repository.First<Vendor>(
        (e => e.Id == model.VendorId),
         e => e.Include(m => m.Ingredients));

    // How to add ingredients to Vendor?
   ingredients.ForEach(ingredient =>
   {
        if(vendor.Ingredients.Any(x => x.IngredientId != ingredient.Id))
        {
            vendor.Ingredients.Add(new VendorIngredient
            {
                VendorId = vendor.Id,
                IngredientId = ingredient.Id
            });
        }
   }
    _repository.Update(vendor);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that vendor is in context in the `AddIngredientsToVendor` method, it should be as simple as the following if you are willing to change the type of the collection on the vendor to be just `Ingreedient`. The concept of a vendor ingredient seems to lose value here as all it does is attach the vendor name to each ingrediet in the colelction of a vendor

```
public void AddIngredientsToVendor(VendorIngredientsRegistrationModel model)
{
    // Ingredients, that I want to add to wendor, Ids: [57, 59, 61, 62]
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = _repository.Fetch<Ingredient>(e => model.IngredientIds.Contains(e.Id),
               e => e.Include(p => p.VendorIngredients)).ToList();

    vendor.Ingredients = ingredients;

    _repository.Update(vendor);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you were to want to keep it as `VendorIngredient` you would need to write a method that would take in both an Ingredient and a Vendor and then map that down to the `VendorIngredient` class

Comment: Sorry, I added a definition for vendor. With `vendor.Ingredients = ingredients;` it says:  "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ProductsManagement.Core.Ingredients.Models.Ingredient>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ProductsManagement.Core.Vendors.Models.VendorIngredient>'"

Comment: Ah, your models are of different types, you will need to write a method to convert `Ingredient` To `VendorIngredient`. 

The value of a vendor ingredient is questionable here in your vendor class though as why does each ingredient within the vendor need the vendor name against it? I would change the type of the Ingredients Collection on the vendor to `Ingredient` rather than `VendorIngredient`
I will modify my answer to fit the new info