# EF Core many to many not saving into join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, many-to-many

I have the following classes

```
public class Travel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public List<ActivityTravel> ActivitityTravels { get; set; } = new List<ActivityTravel>();
}

public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ActivityTravel> ActivitityTravels { get; set; } = new List<ActivityTravel>();
}

public class ActivityTravel
{
    public int TravelId { get; set; }
    public Travel Travel { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
}
```

My **ApplicationDbContext** looks like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityTravel>()
        .HasKey(at => new { at.ActivityId, at.TravelId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityTravel>()
        .HasOne(at => at.Activity)
        .WithMany(a => a.ActivitityTravels)
        .HasForeignKey(at => at.ActivityId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityTravel>()
        .HasOne(at => at.Travel)
        .WithMany(t => t.ActivitityTravels)
        .HasForeignKey(at => at.TravelId);

    //outside of OnModelCreating
    public DbSet<Travel> Travels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ActivityTravel> ActivityTravels { get; set; }
```

A user can add a new **Travel** with a number of already existing **Activites**. But everytime a new Travel is added to the context, nothing is added to **ActivityTravel**.
Here is the code used to add a new **Travel**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddTravel([FromBody] Travel travel)
    {   
        travel.Activities.ForEach(a => travel.ActivitityTravels.Add(new ActivityTravel() { Activity = a, Travel = travel }));
        _context.Travels.Add(travel);

        //dont add activity again
        travel.Activities.ForEach(a => _context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Detached);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

I've followed the example in this question [Saving many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893873/saving-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: Have you tried without detach? If yes - try adding just `ActivitityTravels`: `_context.ActivityTravels.AddRange(travel.ActivitityTravels); _context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: tried that, but then ef tries to add the activities which are already in the database and throws an exception

Comment: Ohh, you can receive already existing stuff. Then you need to [attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-3.1) them first.

Comment: Detaching was the problem and attaching them first helped. Thanks!

Comment: Will add as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not detach your existing `Activities` you need to [attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-3.1) them first before handling other stuff, so they will not be added as duplicates. Something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddTravel([FromBody] Travel travel)
{   
    travel.Activities.ForEach(a => travel.ActivitityTravels.Add(new ActivityTravel() { Activity = a, Travel = travel }));
    _context.AttachRange(travel.Activities);
    _context.Travels.Add(travel);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}
```